# linux debugger detection in multi-thread application using ptrace

Tags: multithreading, debugging, assembly, ptrace

I have to implement debugger detection technique under linux. So the main idea is, my piece of code creates second thread via syscall clone. After that, created thread is supposed to check if debugger is present in while loop, sleeping for a few seconds. My question is how to implement debugger detection via ptrace in multi-thread environment inside infinite loop. My problem is that after calling ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 1, 0) for a second time debugger is detected (that's reasonable and correct of course). So do I have to detach tracer somehow at the end of loop or use ptrace in another way? Here is a piece of code:

```
new_thread:
; PTRACE
xor rdi, rdi
xor rsi, rsi
xor rdx, rdx
inc rdx
xor r10, r10
mov rax, 101 ; ptrace syscall
syscall
cmp rax, 0
jge __nondbg
call _dbg
db 'debugged!', 0xa, 0
_dbg:
mov rdi, 1
pop rsi
mov rdx, 10
mov rax, 1 ; syscall write
syscall
; exit_group call
mov rdi, 127
mov rax, 231 ; exit_group syscall
syscall
__nondbg:
call _nondbg
db 'non-debugged!', 0xa, 0
_nondbg:
mov rdi, 1
pop rsi
mov rdx, 14
mov rax, 1 ; syscall write
syscall
; ==========
; SLEEP.....
; ==========
push 0 ; value should be a parameter
push 5 ; value should be a parameter
mov rdi, rsp
xor rsi, rsi
mov rax, 35 ; syscall nanosleep
syscall ; syscall
pop rax
pop rax
jmp new_thread
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your design forces you to try a loop detection. PTRACE_TRACEME is used by a tracee process to be traced by its parent (after fork). I admit i don't know for sure how this would work when the tracer is another thread in the same process, but i think it wouldn't work very well, as the mechanism of ptrace is based on signals.

If you want to be sure that your (child) process is being attached to the traces, the common approach is to raise a stop signal to allow the tracer to attach. When the execution is resumed, you know the tracer is there.

```
raise(SIGSTOP);
```

Comment: As far as I told before I have to implement debugger-detection in multi-thread environment, so basically I'm asking how to do it using a ptrace. I didn't state that my solution with PTRACE_TRACEME is correct, cause it's incorrect.